# Can't import matplotlib although it is installed

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, python-3.9, arch

I'm on arch linux and until recently I made the error of using pip to install things globally. I tried to remove everything related to python that wasn't tracked by pacman. I then removed pip.

I know of the --user flag for pip but in the end I use the same bunch of basic packages, which I rather install globally using my package manager.

To debug some code I recently needed debug symbols which lead me to compile python myself. After that, I reinstalled it using pacman.

Currently python2 and 3 are installed whereas `python` points to v3.

If I start a REPL and run `help("modules")` I get:

```
>>> help("modules")

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py:12: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  warn("The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0."
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lutris/gui/dialogs/__init__.py:10: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk, WebKit2, GLib
/usr/lib/python3.9/pkgutil.py:108: VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
    Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.
    
  yield from walk_packages(path, info.name+'.', onerror)
```

and then a list of modules including `matplotlib` and `matplotlib_inline`.

If I try to import it inside a REPL I get:

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 24 2021, 12:50:35) 
[GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pascal/matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.path as mpath
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.path'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

Now while writing this I was indeed able to import it once when I opened the REPL in my home dir but I can't reproduce it.

Furthermore `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages` contains

```
matplotlib/
matplotlib_inline/
matplotlib-3.4.1-py3.9.egg-info/  
matplotlib_inline-0.1.2-py3.9.egg-info/
matplotlib-3.4.1-py3.9-nspkg.pth
```

and `pacman -Q` lists

```
python-matplotlib 3.4.1-2
python-matplotlib-inline 0.1.2-1
```

Also the search path (run in REPL) is:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Comment: Could you try to change that file name from `matplotlib.py` to something else?

Comment: thanks - that was some stupid thing I did. Since `""` is in my search path (and also the first one) it seemed to try to import the `matplotlib.py` file. Thanks - feel free to make an answer, even if it's that simple.